# What should be done to the tags related to The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently we have two tags regarding the movies based on Millennium novel series.

- [millennium-trilogy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/millennium-trilogy) and
- [girl-with-dragon-tattoo](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/girl-with-dragon-tattoo)( previously was [girl-dragon-tattoo](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/girl-dragon-tattoo)).

From my point of view, [millennium-trilogy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/millennium-trilogy) tag should be used on the question which involving novel comparison or adaptation question. But it is being used for Swedish trilogy, which seems wired to me.

And for second tag [girl-with-dragon-tattoo](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/girl-with-dragon-tattoo), "the" has to be skipped to fit it into 25 character length. But there are two movies with this name. One is Swedish film and second is american. Are using same tag for both film is good? Or we should require two different tags? I can easily do it myself but 25 character limit is creating problem.

I am raising this question just to know what other community member though about it. Feel free to say what you feel about it.

Comment: I hate this tagging system.

Answer (score 1):

I think [dragon-tattoo-us](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-tattoo-us) and [dragon-tattoo-se](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-tattoo-se) should be good enough.

Further for the eventual american versions of the rest:

- [played-with-fire-us](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/played-with-fire-us) & [played-with-fire-se](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/played-with-fire-se)
- [hornets-nest-us](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hornets-nest-us) & [hornets-nest-se](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hornets-nest-se)

These should all be sufficient.

Comment: Why not use their Swedish titles?

Comment: Män som hatar kvinnor / Flickan som lekte med elden / Luftslottet som sprängdes.  Not exactly easy to tag with.  Not to mention its SE policy to use english unless on a non-english designated SE.

Comment: I think @coleopterist's ideas is not bad because [tag:dragon-tattoo-us] looks little creepy. Why not use tag [tag:Man-som-hatar-kvinnor] instead for Swedish film and [tag:girl-with-dragon-tattoo] for american film

Comment: @AnkitSharma Because it goes against the *language* policy that SE has.

Comment: @TylerShads but [tag:dragon-tattoo-us] doesn't looks good. And looks confusing to new users.

Comment: That's what Tag Wikis are for.  A small hover box appears when you hover over the tag explaining what the tag is to be used for.

Comment: [Meta post about language](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow/13684#13684)